# Sitewide categories for all the blogs in the network

Tags: categories, multisite, navigation, blog-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WordPress Multisite - global categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/wordpress-multisite-global-categories)

I'm trying to do sitewide categories. like when a category is made in the main blog that category is added to all the new blogs created in the network.

Comment: tip — search for "wordpress multisite global categories" (or something like that) on this site and Google. I am sure you'll find many answers.