# New Site URL for Multisite

Tags: multisite

I want to create new networks but am having issues because Wordpress is saying it is invalid. I have a base url of something like http://website.com and then I'm trying to create a new network after that. I'd like my new networks to have a name like:

http://website.com/network1/football/page1
http://website.com/network1/baseball/page2
http://website.com/network1/soccer/page3

http://website.com/network2/football/page1
http://website.com/network2/baseball/page2
http://website.com/network2/soccer/page3

Now I know these are typically categories in under the network but I'm using plugins that don't recognize categories unless they created for the specific plugin and I don't want to have to maintain the same categories all over so it's just easier to create my network with it's own database and not have to worry about it but Wordpress isn't allowing me to create URLs like above. **I'm using sub directories as my choice for multisite in Wordpress instead of sub domains.** Any ideas on how to do this?

**EDIT**: I know I could make the URL be something like http://website.com/network1-soccer/ but I'd ideally like to do it how I have it listed above. I also tried the plugin for the WP Multi Network and was able to acheive the nested structure that I would like with creating those subpages within my multisite defined network. However, when I went to http://website.com/network1/ the page loaded fine but when I went to http://website.com/network1/soccer I got a 404 error.

Comment: Why don't you just put WordPress in a folder called multisite.

Comment: @Wyck I want to have different networks. I've updated my question accordingly. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah you will have to rewrite the urls for each sub-site, I can't test this but check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Comment: @Wyck I never used that. I'm not sure how that would work with my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these, or a combination of, may be what you're looking for:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/site-categories/ (watch its video) has the functionality to put each site on a multisite within categories.

However, your "network of networks" might best be served by http://wpebooks.com/networks/
Plus, it may be able to do the URL scheme you're wanting without needing the Site Categories plugin, above.

Comment: I actually already purchased the networks plugin but the issue I'm having is that it looks like that supports subdomains and not subdirectories. I wasn't able to enable the functionality using subdirectories.

Comment: Subdomains are typically the safer/more recommended setup option because subdirectory has a greater potential for misconfiguration (e.g. you manually create site.com/page1 and there's already a sub-site titled Page1 and is supposed to be at the same URL).

I'd suggest asking the Rennicks (author of that and many other advanced multisite things) if you desire subdirectory instead of subdomain.

Comment: I tried to do this with subdomains and I'm still having issues. I created a new network called `network1.localhost.com` and then went to that Dashboard and tried to add a new site and Wordpress wants to add the site as a new subdomain so it would be `multisite1.network1.localhost.com`. I thought creating the multisite would have given me `network1.localhost.com/multisite`. Any ideas how to do this with this plugin?

Comment: The plugin page says "nested subdomains". It also says "There are many combinations and permutations of URL schemes you can come up with. For example,
one client we had wanted city.state.clientdomain.com, where the city sites were visible blogs, and the state sites were also visible. This provides three levels (domain, subdomain and sub­subdomain) of blogs/sites in the entire network. Each state was created as a new network." The only mention of "directory" is the screenshot at http://wpebooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Sites-%E2%80%B9-andreas-network-%E2%80%94-WordPress_1277133760788.png

Comment: Have you asked Rennick for assistance?

Comment: Yes, the "directory" is what got me thinking that it was possible and the screenshot illustrated it but I didn't see any settings to make that possible. I did send them the question through the contact form and also requested membership into the Networks+ forum on their website but was never accepted yet.

Comment: Maybe try Ron on Twitter: https://twitter.com/sillygrampy

Comment: This plugin actually supports the subddirectory and that is how I got this to work with the "directory". You set up the multisite as a subdirectory install and then when you create your new network in the domain you would make the subdomain in there. So I create domain subdomain.website.com and then when I create a new site it is basically the directory and looks like subdomain.website.com/site1. This worked perfectly. I just also had to enable the wildcard subdomain for this and it's working as I would like thanks to a little support from Ron.

Comment: Hey, very glad to hear it! Thanks for the reward :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no easy solution for your Question, too many unknown things involved.
e.g. how the plugins handle the permalink

Some Ideas:

- use different plugins which support customizing permalinks (e.g actions
  / filters )
- maybe customize - wp-admin/options-permalink.php
- take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Permalinks and url rewrite is no easy stuff to answer without more in depth information

Comment: Well each one of those would be their own multisite just nested in a network. The plugin should have their own tables and if the structure is correct it would know what multisite tables to look at. I don't see an issue with the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for https://wordpress.org/plugins/mu-global-terms/

Note a similar question was asked/answered at [WordPress Multisite - global categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/wordpress-multisite-global-categories) so that may help you out as well.

Note: it wasn't clear if you wanted site.com/network1/category to also include posts from site.com/network2/category but that's a slightly different thing.

Comment: I don't want them to include the same posts. In matter of fact the part that you have listed as a category really isn't a cateogry. It's a new multisite within the network. They would actually have different pages under it. So a full page URL would be something like this: `site.com/network1/football/team-members` and then another one would be something like `site.com/network2/soccer/team-members`. These would be completely different multisites. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, so that'd actually be a network of networks. This is a more advanced question - I'm sure I've seen a plugin for that somewhere, but there would be a myriad of questions before determining whether it's actually a good idea since it's not a common configuration. The added complexity might be buying you a bigger problem than the one you're solving.

That said, I think the issue *may* have to do with domain mapping to the various subfolders. Again, it'd take more analysis.